# How to configure module's 'content-root' in build.gradle with IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Now I'm using IntelliJ.

For some reasons, I want to configure module's settings without "by-person" action.

The settings I want to do is "add content-root" in module settings.

I'm using queryDSL and it generate new source-set(==module) which is named "generated".

And I want to add content-root under main module.

Already I know that I can add content-root using my hand :)

But I hope there is a way to do this configuration (i,e.. plug-in 'idea') and

if u know some way , please let me know.

[module-settings in Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbmB0.png)

Comment: I *think* you're asking how you can get your generated sources to appear correctly with QueryDSL?  If that's the case, you should rephrase your question specifically to be about that instead of about IntelliJ, since going the other way makes for an incredibly tough read.

Comment: @Makoto
 First of all, thank you for u r reply. 
Well , I already got success to get generated sources. But the problem is , I checked the option which makes every created sourceSets to module. So the generated sourceSets is created to module. But for using this generated sourceSets in main module , I found out that I should add the generated things to content-root in main module.
So that's why I ask to do this configuration automatically.